# WCF REST service how to return 401 Unauthorize code but also an object?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF REST service that has to check a token to allow or deny access to users.
If the token is wrong or expired, I am requested to return a code 401 AND an object.

I usually return a 401 code in this way:

`throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Unauhtorized);`

but doing so I'm not able to return anything.

How can I include also something like:

```
return new AuthenticationResponse
                {
                    Succeded = false,
                    Token = "",
                    Message = "Invalid token."
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var response = new AuthenticationResponse
                {
                    Succeded = false,
                    Token = "",
                    Message = "Invalid token."
                };
throw new WebFaultException<AuthenticationResponse>(response, HttpStatusCode.Unauhtorized);
```